# Sed interpreter script - In place

Tags: sed

Is it possible to run sed interpreter script "in place" (-i)?

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -if
#sed commands...
```

This gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: `f'
```

I have tried to search for it but I've found only `#!/usr/bin/sed -nf` (which for some reason works fine).

BTW: I know I could run bash script and the `sed -i` command, but it just doesn't feel right :D

EDIT:

I'm just correcting some JSON config file. Using python JSON parser removes all formatting and comments(!) so that isn't working for me. I have tried all possible combinations of `sed -i -f` `sed -f -i` etc.

EDIT:

For those unbelievers: Here is the whole script. Hope you like it :D

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -if 

# Tabs - change height
/\/\/ Tab set/,/\}\,/ {
    s/"tab_width": .*,/"tab_width": 50,/;
    s/"tab_height": .*,/"tab_height": 27,/;
}

# VScroll bar
/\/\/ Overlay vertical puck/,/\}\,/ {

# Width
s/"content_margin": .*/"content_margin": [3,38],/
# Color
/content_margin/ {
    a\
    "layer0.tint":[173,216,230],
    a\
    "layer0.opacity": 0.2,
    }
}

# HScroll bar - width
/\/\/ Overlay horizontal puck/,/\}\,/ {
    s/"content_margin": .*/"content_margin": [16,3],/
}

# Status bar - height
/\/\/ Status bar container/,/\}\,/ {
    s/"content_margin": .*/"content_margin": [15, 4]/
}

# Side bar - rows
/\/\/ Sidebar tree || entries/,/\}\,/ {
    s/"row_padding": .*/"row_padding": [8,5],/
    s/"indent_offset": .*/"indent_offset": 10,/
}

# Side bar - folder icon
/\/\/ Sidebar folder opened/,/\}\,/ {
s/"layer0.texture": "Seti_UI\/icons\/folder_open@2x.png",/"layer0.texture":          "Seti_UI\/icons\/folder@2x.png",/
}
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Post your complete `sed` command. Try `sed --help` to see if  `f` is supported and make sure you use it correct. `sed -f scriptfile file`

Comment: `sed -i -f scriptfile file` and no `#!/usr/bin/sed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14894), this will not work because it is not (portably) possible to use more than one argument on a `#!` line. The answer comes with acceptable (at least, to me) workarounds.

Comment: So, I will have to run ```sed``` from bash script after all :D

Comment: well, it doesn't have to be bash, just any language you can write a sed NOOP in and exec sed from.

Comment: I will cope with that. Thank you :)